# How to mock in express with Typescript and Mocha library

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mocha.js, chai

How to mock 'Request' in Mocha using express with Typescript?
Current solution is following:

```
describe("Authorization middleware", () => {
  it("Fails when no authorization header", () => {
    const req = {
      get: () => {
        return null;
      },
    };
    expect(isAuth(req as Request, {}, () => {}));
  });
});
```

I have got an error `Conversion of type '{ get: () => null; }' to type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Is forcing 'unknown' type the only solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http) package to create the mockups of the `request` and `response` objects for `express` routing functions.

E.g.

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import httpMocks from 'node-mocks-http';

const isAuth = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // your code under test
}

describe("Authorization middleware", () => {
  it("Fails when no authorization header", () => {
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest();
    const res = httpMocks.createResponse()
    expect(isAuth(req, res));
  });
});
```

The return value of `httpMocks.createRequest()` API is [`MockRequest`](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http/blob/v1.12.1/lib/index.d.ts#L110) type, its generic parameter is constrained by express `Request` type. The `Request` type is a subset of the `MockRequest` type, so it matches the `Request` type.